# How to refresh my database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I was creating an mvc application and i had a model class with a dbcontext function the variables were in the same file. I added another field and changed the code in the edit create delete details and index views but i now get an error saying

"The model backing the 'GameDBContext' context has changed since the database was created. Either manually delete/update the database, or call Database.SetInitializer with an IDatabaseInitializer instance. For example, the DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges strategy will automatically delete and recreate the database, and optionally seed it with new data."

```
    Imports System.Data.Entity

    Public Class Game
        Public Property ID() As Integer
        Public Property Name() As String
        Public Property Genre() As String
        Public Property Price() As Decimal
        Public Property Developer() As String
    End Class
    Public Class GameDBContext
        Inherits DbContext
        Public Property Games() As DbSet(Of Game)
    End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add a initializer method to the `Application_Start` method in `Global.asax` file. Ex:-

```
 Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<GameDBContext>());
```

Comment: i added that after converting to vb and and got the error "Error 'Database' is ambiguous, imported from the namespaces or types 'System.Data.Entity, System.Data.Entity.DbContext'."

Comment: In my case, I added `using System.Data.Entity;` to the top of `Global.asax`, and added this line to the `Application_Start` method: `Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<Models.PersonDBContext>());`

Answer (score 0):

Since it sounds like you're using a code first approach in developing your application, here are a couple of links that might help you:

[code first development with entity framework 4](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx)

[Code First/Entity Framework 4.1 Videos and Articles on MSDN](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/code-first-entity-framework-4-1-videos-and-articles-on-msdn/)

All of these can give you a better understanding of what is happening and how to work around having your database change on you.

In short, since you added another property, the entity framework table in your database is now longer in sync with your class. Since it's no longer in sync, you must manually delete this database in order to regenerate it, or you must create an initialization for the database. All of these concepts are better described in the links I have provided.

Good luck, and hope these help you some.